# 2checkout multiple notification problems

Tags: payment, 2checkout

We have been using 2checkout as one of a payment providers for a while now. We run a subscription based service that activate a set amount of time on the users account when we receive a notification.

For some reason in the past few days a number of users (not all) have been receiving notifications of Order Created 3 times, 1 every half an hour.

This is giving then 3 times their purchased time on our system.

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?

I originally thought it was a case of waiting for the fraud status as on one account, the status was 'wait' for the first 2 notifications. But I have now seen with other users that the fraud check has passed on all 3 notification.

Any help would be appreciated.

Cheers

Nadeem

Comment: Hi i am facing same problem, have you resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

2Checkout INS notification will attempt to retry for a total of 3 attempts if a successful HTTP response is not returned by your server. You should be able to confirm that they are failing by checking the Failed logs in your 2Checkout account under the Notifications tab. Please contact 2Checkout tech support at techsupport@2checkout.com for assistance with troubleshooting the issue. They will be able to pull the logs to show the response from your server when the notification fails.